# How do I kill Countdowntimer when I exit viewcontroller, without pressing the stop button?

Tags: ios, timer, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer. When it hits 0 secs, the timer is repeating until I press a stop button, but when I leave the viewcontroller without pressing the stop button, it's in the background, and when I go back to countdownViewController it won't stop.

How do I kill it when I exit viewcontroller without pressing the stop button?

Swift 4.2

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clearer what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have stopped the countdown timer on click of the Stop button. You can do the same coding in viewcontroller's viewDidDisappear method:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        // Put the same code which works on Stop button click
    }
```

I hope this helps.